# Web scraping using python-beginner level

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hello I am new into python . practicing web scraping with some demo sites .
I am trying to scrape this website http://books.toscrape.com/ and want to extract

1. href
2. name/title
3. start rating/star-rating
4. price/price_color
5. in-stock availbility/instock availability

i written a basic code which goes to each book level.

but after that i am clueless as how i can extract those information.

```
import requests
from csv import reader,writer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url= "http://books.toscrape.com/"

r = requests.get(base_url)

htmlContent = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent,'html.parser')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
```

Comment: You have to look in the page source of the website (`right click->view page source` or similar) and find the tags under which the information you want resides. Then you can use `soup.find_all()` with the relevant tags to extract the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find you the href and name for every book. You could also extract some other other information if you want.

```
import requests
from csv import reader,writer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url= "http://books.toscrape.com/"

r = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

def extract_info(soup):
    href = []
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True): 
        if a.text:
            if "catalogue" in a["href"]:
                href.append(a['href'])
                        
    name = []
    for a in soup.find_all('a', title=True):
        name.append(a.text)

    return href, name

href, name = extract_info(soup)

print(href[0], name[0])
```

the output will be the href and name for the first book

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach using python - **[requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io)** and **BeautifulSoup**. I have fetched the page URL from website itself after inspecting the network section > Doc tab of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

1. First it will take the Page URL which is created using, page no parameter and then doing a GET request.
2. URL is dynamic which will get created after finishing of an iteration. You will notice that PAGE_NO param will get incremented after each iteration.
3. After getting the data script will parse the HTML code using **html5.parser** library.
4. Finally it will iterate all over the list of books fetched in each iteration or page for ex:- Title, Hyperlink, Price, Stock Availability and rating.

> There are 50 pages and 1k results below script will extract all the books details one page per iteration

```
    import requests
    from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    def scrap_books_data():

    PAGE_NO = 1  # Page no parameter which will get incremented after every iteration

    while True:
    print('Creating URL to scrape books data for ', str(PAGE_NO))

    URL = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-' + str(PAGE_NO) + '.html' #dynamic URL which will get created after every iteration
    response = requests.get(URL,verify=False) # GET request to fetch data from site
    soup = bs(response.text,'html.parser') #Parse HTML data using 'html5.parser'

    extracted_books_data = soup.find_all('article', class_ = 'product_pod') # find all articles tag where book details are nested

    if len(extracted_books_data) == 0: #break the loop and exit from the script if there in no more data available to process
        break
    else:
        for item in range(len(extracted_books_data)): #iterate over the list of extracted books
            print('-' * 100)
            print('Title : ', extracted_books_data[item].contents[5].contents[0].attrs['title'])
            print('Link : ', extracted_books_data[item].contents[5].contents[0].attrs['href'])
            print('Rating : ', extracted_books_data[item].contents[3].attrs['class'][1])
            print('Price : ', extracted_books_data[item].contents[7].contents[1].text.replace('Â',''))
            print('Availability : ', extracted_books_data[item].contents[7].contents[3].text.replace('\n','').strip())
            print('-' * 100)
        PAGE_NO += 1 #increment page no by 1 to scrape next page data
    scrap_books_data()
```